# image of UIbutton is stretched in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have added a right bar button in my navigation bar, and then assign image to the UIButton and set the size to 20px * 20px

the view is good in editor, but when I run the app in simulator, the image is very stretched, can anyone help me please

image is here

[image]

Comment: Do you have auto layout constraints on the label?

Comment: A right bar button is not a UIButton (it's a UIBarButtonItem). Perhaps you should give more details about what you're doing.

Comment: @ATyshka no I am not using auto layout

Comment: @matt I have added a UIButton inside the Bar Button Item, it working fine when I use text button, but I want to use icons instead of text, that is what I want

Comment: did you selected the default system icon for the UIBarButton? as for the both button you are saying there is default system icon which you can use directly

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIButton`, set `button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Comment: self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Answer (score 0):

Control Click and Drag from Button to View Controller as IBOutlet

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
yourButtonOutletName.image.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

//        
}
```